# Which one's correct - "this two" or "these two"?

Tags: pronouns, demonstratives

I’m aware that ‘this’ is used for a singular thing while ‘these’ is used for plural. However, I also see people who use the phrase ‘this two’ so I’m not sure which one’s correct.

Comment: Can you provide a sentence with *this two*, which you have  come across anywhere?

Comment: So are you or are you not aware what is correct? And if you are, then why would you wonder whether people who you know are wrong are right?

Comment: @RegDwigнt I'm wondering if there's an instance where "this two" is more appropriate than "these two"

Comment: Other than Vocoder's signage, either *this pair* or *those two*.

Whoever downvoted that, it seems to me the only 'unreasonable' thing about the question would be if it belonged to ELL, not EL&U… which would be a bit of a slip, not any kind of problem.

Answer (score 5):

"These two" is correct because two is a plural, as you say. The only sensible exception I can come up with is in a very specific verbal discussion.

> A signwriter is having trouble deciding how to write a numeral, so he calls a colleague over.
>
> "I'm trying to find way to make this price signage really eye-catching. So which do you prefer? This two," he asked, pointing to a curling, cursive numeral, "or that two?"